# Display Friendly URL in Content Query Web Part

Tags: content-query-web-part, url, hyperlink, term-store, seo

I've got a news page where a **Content Query Web Part (CQWB)** is showing the latest news (Article Pages, sorted by date, with byline and picture) and it works very well. But now we're making the site more SEO compliant and we need to change some things.

Unfortunately I couldn't find out how to display the friendly URL of an Article page at the CQWP. The CQWP only links to the ASPX page even if I create the friendly URL at the term store management.

How can I let the CQWP display the friendly url of the page and not the .aspx page link?

You can find the site here: http://tecmasters.net/en/news

This is how the custom fields look like:

[image: This is how the custom fields look like]